# Discord.py Read last line of txt file and send as loop python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am experimenting with making my own little discord bot which read the last line of Apache.txt log and post that last line into discord channel with command $start. what im stuck now is how to make the bot post to channel if the text file has been update instead of keep posting the same last line. Please help

Thank you very much

```
import discord
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

from discord.ext import commands, tasks

load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    task_loop.start(ctx)

@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def task_loop(ctx):
    file = open(r"Apache.txt", "r")
    content = file.readlines()
    await ctx.send(content[-1])

bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Comment: don't forget to `file.close()`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by putting content in a variable like this

```py
import discord
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv

from discord.ext import commands, tasks

load_dotenv()
DISCORD_TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")

last_content = None

@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    task_loop.start(ctx)

@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def task_loop(ctx):
    global last_content
    file = open(r"Apache.txt", "r")
    content = file.readlines()
    file.close()

    if content[-1] != last_content:
        await ctx.send(content[-1])
        last_content = content[-1]

bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Note that this will not work if the bot reboots, it would be necessary to save the last line in a file instead of putting it in variable